# Is there an agreed-upon feature set that defines segments as vowels?

Tags: terminology, phonology, vowels

I have a feeling the answer is no, and that there are complications involved, but I was considering this:

[-consonantal, +syllabic]

This would first remove all consonants, leaving e, u, i, and others, and then ensure that the remaining are syllabic, which would rule out glides (like j, w). All vowels should be syllabic, yes?

Comment: Are you asking for the set of features that vowels can have, such as nasalization, roundedness, front/back, mid/central/low, tone, creaky voice, etc? If not, please consider rewording the question title.

Comment: @hippietrail: I think the question is whether there exists a set of features that defines the term "vowel".

Comment: You *could* define vowels that way, but then how would you define "consonantal"?

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail: Yes it seems so from the question body, but in that case the question title definitely has to be changed to match the body. The question body itself could probably be clearer too.

Comment: I'm not sure that vowels have to be syllabic. For instance a group of vowels may combine to form a single diphthong or triphthong, or be pronounced separtely. Then there are the two kinds of schwa in some analyses of Hebrew, one being syllabic and the other not. Then there are moraic languages like Japanese. It's even possible to imagine some language could have a division between major/syllabic/stressed vowels and minor/nonsyallabic/unstressed ones, though I have no idea if any such language exists.

Comment: @hippietrail: I don't think "vowel" even has a well-defined meaning. Several languages, like Slovak, have syllabic obstruents that pattern as vowels. Spanish seems to have 3 levels (vowels/semivowels/consonants). The American English R is called a consonant even though it is a syllabic sonorant that behaves like /i/, which is considered a vowel.

Comment: Yes, @Mechanicalsnail has the right interpretation. If "vowel" does not have a well-defined meaning, then I guess there isn't a set of features that defines segments as vowels.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail: Yes this is another good point. Tough like "phoneme", "vowel" seems to one of those linguistics concepts that stick around because it's useful despite not holding up to every kind of modern analysis.

Comment: Still I would dispute that vowel doesn't have a well-defined meaning. This is why we also have the terms "semivowel" and "syllabic consonant".

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the wording. I think the answer would be "no" given that the same sound might be considered a consonant in one language and a vowel in another. Thus the feature set alone is not sufficient to categorise a segment one way or the other, other factors must be taken into account, possibly including "tradition"...

Comment: @hippietrail: In the context of a particular language, it's often possible to clearly define "vowel"s. It's similar to language-dependent terms like "rhotic" or "syllable"; the terms encompass a vague idea whose boundaries depend on the language.

Comment: Is it right that `feature`s are set for all languages though. What about `segment`s? Is that a cross-linguistic term or can it also depend on each language?

Answer (score 5):

A decent answer by @hippietrail from the comments above:

> I think the answer would be "no" given that the same sound might be
>   considered a consonant in one language and a vowel in another. Thus
>   the feature set alone is not sufficient to categorise a segment one
>   way or the other, other factors must be taken into account, possibly
>   including "tradition"...

Ultimately, the feature set notion is not perfectly adequate in describing our notions of vowels.

Comment: Yes. What counts as a "vowel" is different from one language to another; sometimes quite different. Many phenomena like epenthesis or vocalization in morphology produce spurious "vowels" that have no phonemic realization. Contrariwise, phonemic vowels are often converted to gestures like labialization or palatalization, or to consonants with those properties.